How many natural operations on subsets are there?
How many operations are there on subsets of a set that are compatible with images of maps? Of course, we can take unions, but are these all? Spoiler: No.
To formalize this, let $P : \mathbf{Set} \to \mathbf{Set}$ be the covariant power set functor.
Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. How many natural transformations
$$P^n \to P$$
are there? Such a transformation $\alpha$ consists of an $n$-ary operation on the subsets of any set $X$,
$$\alpha_X : P(X)^n \to P(X),$$
such that for all maps $f : X \to Y$ we have
$$f(\alpha_X(U_1,\dotsc,U_n)) = \alpha_Y(f(U_1),\dotsc,f(U_n))$$
as subsets of $Y$. Let us call $\alpha$ just a subset operation.
For example, for every subset $T \subseteq \{1,\dotsc,n\}$ we have the $n$-ary subset operation
$$(U_1,\dotsc,U_n) \mapsto \bigcup_{i \in T} U_i,$$
and one might think first that these are all.
The case $n = 0$ is easy, we have a natural subset $U_X \subseteq X$ for every set $X$ such that $f(U_X) = U_Y$ for all $f : X \to Y$. Taking $X = \emptyset$, we must have $U_X = \emptyset$, and then $U_Y = \emptyset$, for all $Y$. So this is the only solution.
The case $n = 1$ is also a good exercise. Let $\alpha : P \to P$ be a unary subset operation. Applying naturality to $i : U \hookrightarrow X$ shows $\alpha_X(U) = \alpha_U(U)$, in particular $\alpha_X(U) \subseteq U$. In particular, $\alpha_X(\emptyset) = \emptyset$. Let $\star$ be the singleton set. Then $\alpha_\star(\star)$ is either $\emptyset$ or $\star$. If it is $\emptyset$, then $\alpha_X(U) = \emptyset$ for all $U \subseteq X$: If $U = \emptyset$, this is already known. If $U \neq \emptyset$, then for the unique map $f : X \to \star$ we have $f(\alpha_X(U)) = \alpha_\star(f(U)) = \alpha_\star(\star) = \emptyset$ and hence $\alpha_X(U) = \emptyset$. Now assume $\alpha_\star(\star) = \star$. Then for $X \neq \emptyset$ we have $\alpha_X(X) \neq \emptyset$, since the unique map $f : X \to \star$ maps this to $\alpha_\star(\star) \neq \emptyset$. For all bijective maps $f : X \to X$ we have $f(\alpha_X(X)) = \alpha_X(f(X)) = \alpha_X(X)$. The only non-empty subset of $X$ that is invariant under all permutations is $X$ itself. Hence, $\alpha_X(X) = X$, and then $\alpha_X(U) = \alpha_U(U) = U$.
So there are only the two obvious unary subset operations, $\alpha(U) = \emptyset$ and $\alpha(U) = U$.
For $n = 2$ we have at least the following four subset operations: a pair of subsets $(U,V)$ is mapped to one of these:
$$\emptyset, ~ U, ~ V, ~ U \cup V$$
However, there is a fifth subset operation! It is defined by
$$U \cup_s V := \begin{cases} U \cup V & U \neq \emptyset \text{ and } V \neq \emptyset \\ \emptyset & U = \emptyset \text{ or } V = \emptyset \end{cases}$$
An elementary calculation shows that, indeed,
$$f(U \cup_s V) = f(U) \cup_s f(V).$$
The crucial property of the image is here that $f(U) = \emptyset \iff U = \emptyset$. Notice that $\cup_s$ is associative, commutative, but it lacks a neutral element. I call $\cup_s$ the "stubborn union". It refuses to take the union when one of the sets is empty. Let me know if this already has a name.
I did not expect any other subset operation apart from the unions! But that's life, I guess (it would be better with pointed sets). Of course, you can combine this idea with the unions to generate many more subset operations for $n > 2$. For example, $(U,V,W) \mapsto U \cup ( V \cup_s W)$ is a subset operation for $n = 3$.
The exact number seems to be connected with partitions and be something like $$\sum_{k \leq n} \binom{n}{k} B_k = B_{n+1},$$
where $B_n$ is the Bell number, but I am not sure. Apparently for the the counting we also need to understand the compatibility conditions between $\cup_s$ and $\cup$ (if there are any), that is, the operad structure on $\hom(P^\bullet,P)$.
For this question, let me only focus on $n = 2$ though.
Question. Are the five operations described above the only binary subset operations?
Here is what I have tried. Let $\alpha : P^2 \to P$ be a binary subset operation. We have $\alpha(U,V) \subseteq U \cup V$. We can define three unary subset operations from it, by mapping $U$ either to $\alpha(U,\emptyset)$, $\alpha(\emptyset,U)$, or $\alpha(U,U)$. Now use the already known classification of unary subset operations. Let's look for example at the case that $\alpha(U,\emptyset) = \emptyset$ and $\alpha(\emptyset,U) = U$ hold, for all $U \subseteq X$. Now the case $\alpha(U,U) = \emptyset$ is easy to deal with, you can quite easily deduce $\alpha(U,V) = \emptyset$ by using the unique map $X \to \star$. The harder case is $\alpha(U,U) = U$ for all $U$. How can I then verify that $\alpha(U,V) = U \cup_s V$? Or is there even another operation that I missed? It suffices to consider subsets of $\{0,1\}$ (apply naturality to maps $X \to \{0,1\}$). So we only need to calculate $\alpha(\{0\},\{0,1\}$) and $\alpha(\{0\},\{1\})$, but how is that possible?
And this is only one of the cases! I also don't know how to proceed with the case $\alpha(U,\emptyset) = U$, $\alpha(\emptyset,U)=U$. Of course we would be done if $\alpha$ was monotonic in both of its arguments, but there is no a priori reason for this!
It is worthwile mentioning that the contravariant version is much easier to handle, since the contravariant power set functor is a representable functor, so that Yoneda kicks in. Our functor $P$ however is very far from being representable. This makes the question so interesting.

Probably stupid question: why doesn't intersection work?

Because the maps are not necessarily injective.

$\alpha$ determines and is determined by determined by $\alpha(U,\emptyset)$ and $\alpha(\emptyset,V)$, and $\alpha(U, V)$ where $U$ and $V$ range over nonempty subsets of $X$. Are there any naturality constraints connecting these three systems? To me it looks like any independent combination of choices for these three yields a subset operation. E.g. the "stubborn projection" $\alpha(U,V) = U$ unless $V=\emptyset$ in which case it is $\emptyset$. Do I misunderstand?

I think it should help to write $P$ as the coproduct of the terminal functor and the nonempty power set functor $P'$ defined by $P'(X) = P(X) \setminus {\emptyset}$. The stubborn operations seem to be induced by this decomposition. Have you thought about using this yet? It seems plausible that the natural operations on $P'$ are only the unions, but I'm not sure how to go about a proof.

Can we use some parametricity magic from functional programming to answer the question?

I think the "stubborn" operations can be understood constructively in terms of the natural map $P (X) \to P (1)$ and mixed operations $P (X)^n \times P (1)^m \to P (X)$. For example, there is a natural mixed operation $P (X) \times P (1) \to P (X)$ sending $(U, \phi)$ to ${ x \in X : x \in U \text{ and } \phi }$, where we conflate subsets of $1$ with constant truth values. This accounts for both the natural unary operations you have already found, since the elements of $P (1)$ can be considered constants, as well as the "stubborn" union and "stubborn" projections already mentioned.

It might be helpful to think of the linear/additive analogue of this: we are dealing with not merely a module but one with equipped with a homomorphism to the base ring. This extra gadget enriches the available natural operations.

@GabrielC.Drummond-Cole Oh there are (at least) seven binary subset operations then! Good catch. Still wondering how to prove that these are all.

I think there may be some chance to establish a connection between natural transformation between $P^n \Rightarrow P$ and natural transformation between $n \times  (-)$ and  $(-)$. That's because in some informal (!) sense $P$ is representable.

It occurs to me that having $P (1)$ around means there are at least $P (1)^{P (1)^n}$ distinct $(n + 1)$-ary operations: for the first $n$ variables, map each one down to $P (1)$, apply an arbitrary $n$-ary operation on them, then combine it with the last variable by "scalar multiplication".  This means it grows at least as fast as $2^{2^{n-1}}$...!

Ah, I see where Tobias Fritz's decomposition comes from too: because of the natural augmentation $P (X) \to P (1)$, we can think of everything happening not in $\textbf{Set}$ but rather $\textbf{Set}_{/ P(1)}$. The fibre over $\bot$ is, of course, the constant ${ \emptyset }$ functor and the fibre over $\top$ is the inhabited subset functor. But there are fewer natural transformations $P^n \Rightarrow P$ if we require compatibility with the augmentation.

Here is a conjectural classification: Operations $\tau : P(X)^n \to P(X)$ correspond to maps $M : P([n]) \to P([n])$ that are deflationary, i.e. $Ma \subseteq a$.  A deflationary map $M$ induces an operation $\varphi_M$ by taking $\phi_M(X_1,\ldots,X_n) = \bigcup_{i \in M({ j \mid X_j \neq \emptyset})} X_i$.  Conversely, an operation $\tau$ induces a map $D_\tau $ by sending $a \in P([n])$ to $\tau(a \cap {1}, a \cap {2}, \ldots)$, deflationary by naturality.  Certainly $D_(\phi_M) = D$; I hope naturality should imply $\phi_(D_\tau) = \tau$, but I don’t have time to finish the job now…

In particular, for $n=2$, this tells us that there are at least 16 operations (exactly 16 if the conjecture is correct), including non-monotonic ones such as: $\mu(U,V)$ is $V$ if $U = \emptyset$, and $\emptyset$ otherwise.

Here is a classification: Natural operations $\tau : P(-)^n \to P(-)$ correspond to maps $M : P([n]) \to P([n])$ that are deflationary, i.e. $M a \subseteq a$ for each $a$.
A deflationary map $M$ on $P([n])$ induces an operation $\varphi_M : P(X)^n \to P(X)$ by taking $\varphi_M(U_1,\ldots,U_n) = \bigcup_{i \in M(\{ j | U_j\, \text{inhabited} \})} U_i$. Conversely, a natural operation $\tau$ induces a map $D_\tau : P([n]) \to P([n])$ by sending $a \in P([n])$ to $\tau(a \cap \{1\}, a \cap \{2\}, \ldots)$. This is deflationary by naturality: for each $a \in P([n])$, the tuple $(a \cap \{1\},\ldots)$ is in the image of $P(a)^n \hookrightarrow P([n])^n$, and so its image under $\tau$ is in the image of $P(a) \hookrightarrow P([n])$.
Now certainly for any deflationary map $M$, $D_{\varphi_M} = M$ (by direct calculation).  Conversely, for any natural operation $\tau : P(-)^n \to P(-)$, naturality implies that $\varphi_{D_\tau} = \tau$ as follows: Given $U_1,\ldots,U_n \subseteq X$, write $a = \{ i \in [n] \mid U_i\, \text{inhabited} \}$, and $\vec a = (a \cap \{1\}, \ldots, a \cap \{n\}) \in P([n])^n$.  We need to show that $\tau(U_1,\ldots,U_n) = \bigcup_{i \in \tau(\vec a)} U_i$.
Take the disjoint sum $U = \coprod_i U_i = \{ (i,x) \mid i \in [n],\, x \in U_i\}$, with natural maps $U \to [n]$ and $U \to X$ given by first and second projections. Write $\vec U$ for $(\{1\} \times U_1,\ldots, \{n\} \times U_n) \in P(U)^n$.  Now the image of $\vec U$ under first projection $P(U)^n \to P([n])^n$ is exactly the set $\vec a$ from above; so the image of $\tau(\vec U)$ under $P(U) \to P([n])$ must be exactly $\tau(\vec a)$.  So $\tau(\vec U) \in P(U)$ will meet the summand $\{i\} \times U_i$ precisely when $i \in \tau(\vec a)$.  Moreover, in that case, it must contain the whole summand, by naturality under all permutations of $U_i$ (*). So $\tau(\vec U)$ consists precisely of the union of all summands $\{i\} \times U_i$ for $i \in \tau(\vec a)$.  So now by naturality under the map $U \to X$, we get that $\tau(U_1,\ldots,U_n)$ is the union of these $U_i$, as required.
This proves the claimed correspondence between natural $n$-ary operations and deflationary maps on $P([n])$.  For counting, a little calculation shows that there are $2^{n2^{n-1}}$ such maps.
This correspondence also restricts to a monotone version: an operation will be monotone precisely when its corresponding deflationary map is.

Zhen Lin asks in comments: How constructive is this?  The counting of deflationary maps certainly requires LEM; but the correspondence between natural operations $P(-)^n \to P$ and deflationary maps on $P([n])$ turns out to be entirely constructive.  The one non-constructive step in the argument above is (*); constructively this point is a bit harder, so I’m leaving the classical version above and giving the constructive version here.  In the unary case, we essentially need to show: for any natural $\tau : P(-) \to P(-)$, if $P_X(X)$ is inhabited, then $P_X(X) = X$. I’ll just show this case; the $n$-ary version needed at (*) is similar.
Classically, Martin argues this in the question: by naturality, $P_X(X)$ must be invariant under all permutations of $X$, and the only inhabited invariant subset is $X$ itself. Constructively, we can’t construct transpositions on an arbitrary set $X$ to make that second step — but by several appeals to naturality, we can reduce it back to the case of a discrete set, where the classical argument does work:

By naturality along $X \to 1$, $\tau_1(1) = 1$.
By naturality along $Y \to 1$, $\tau_Y(Y)$ is inhabited for any inhabited $Y$.
In particular, $\tau_2(2)$ is inhabited — and since $2$ has decidable equality, its only permutation-invariant inhabited subset is $2$, so $\tau_2(2) = 2$.
So for any coproduct of inhabited sets $Y+Z$, naturality along $Y+Z \to 1+1=2$ shows that $\tau_{Y+Z}(Y+Z)$ must meet both summands. In particular, $\tau_{Y+1}(Y+1)$ must include the adjoined point.
Now going back to the original $X$, for any $x \in X$, naturality along $[1_X,x] : X+1 \to X$ shows that $x \in \tau_X(X)$; so $\tau_X(X) = X$ as desired.


I suppose "non-intersection" should be "non-empty intersection"? Anyway, inquiring minds want to know: does this require LEM? The part where we permute $U_i$ looks suspect...

@ZhenLin: Yes — as far as I can see, it’s using LEM there (and also in the counting, of course).  I don”t see a way to do this constructively… would be very interested to know if one can.  The difficulty shows up already in the unary case.

Right! I don't even know how to prove that $P (1) \to P (1)$ is deflationary. Naturality says $\bot$ goes to $\bot$ and LEM allows us to conclude the map is deflationary but could we have some funny business away from $\bot$ in general...?

@ZhenLin: The deflationary property is constructive: for any $U \subseteq X$, $U \in P(X)$ is in the image of $P(U) \to P(X)$, so $\tau_X(U)$ is an image of $\tau_U(U)$ under $P(U) \to P(X)$, so $\tau_X(U) \subseteq U \subseteq X$.  I think the non-constructive part can be reduced to one claim: “If $\tau_X(X)$ is inhabited, then it’s $X$.” — assuming this, all the rest of my answer’s argument follows constructively, if phrased carefully-enough.  But I’m not sure whether the claim is constructively provable…  I can’t see a proof, but I also don’t see that it implies any constructive taboo.

Great answer! By the way, for $n=3$ this gives a staggering amount of $4096$ operations. My initial guess was $2^3$ ... !

If $I$ is any set, then operations $P^I \to P$ should also correspond to the deflationary maps $P(I) \to P(I)$, by the same proof.

@ZhenLin: I think I have a constructive replacement for that argument, but it’s a bit more fiddly; will edit to add it.

Wonderful! I tried playing around with the partial map classifier to see if there is a way to replace automorphisms but quickly realised I have no idea what I'm doing.

In a comment Peter LeFanu Lumsdaine has conjectured a classification, which shows that there are $16$ (!) binary subset operations. They can be combined from $1 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 4$ independent cases. For reference, let me write them down:

$\alpha(\emptyset,\emptyset)$ must be $\emptyset$

For non-empty sets $U$, $\alpha(U,\emptyset)$ can be one of $\emptyset$, $U$

For non-empty sets $V$, $\alpha(\emptyset,V)$ can be one of $\emptyset$, $V$

For non-empty sets $U,V$, $\alpha(U,V)$ can be one of $\emptyset, U, V, U \cup V$.


Update. According to the now proven classification in terms of deflationary maps, let me also mention the corresponding $16$ deflationary maps $M : P([2]) \to P([2])$:

$M(\emptyset)$ must be $\emptyset$
$M(\{1\})$ can be one of $\emptyset, \{1\}$
$M(\{2\})$ can be one of $\emptyset, \{2\}$
$M(\{1,2\})$ can be one of $\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1,2\}$


12 and 16 are the same. Why use ChatGPT for something like this when it's easier to write a program to generate it in any half-decent programming language? Or, indeed, it can be expressed more compactly without using any other tools: $\alpha(\emptyset, \emptyset) = \emptyset$; $\alpha(\emptyset, V)$ is either $\emptyset$ or $V$; $\alpha(U, \emptyset)$ is either $\emptyset$ or $U$; and $\alpha(U, V)$ is one of $\emptyset, U, V, U \cup V$ where $U$, $V$ are non-empty in the cases where mentioned and the cases are independent, giving $16$ options.

In terms of avoiding scrolling, you can always (ab)use spoilers, entered blockquote-like as >! (see MO syntax). \ In addition to #12 and #16 pointed out by @PeterTaylor, #11 and #15 were the same.  I edited to correct.

@PeterTaylor To me this situation looks like the "best-case scenario" that people sometimes propose for the use of LLMs for mathematics: a small, systematic task, with finite output that can be quickly checked, such that one could give a LLM a natural-language prompt to generate probably-correct output in less time than one could write a little script, in Python or whatever, to generate the correct output. I think it is remarkable that even in this scenario, ChatGPT still stumbled, so that in the end it would have been faster to just write the script. A worthwhile experiment IMO.

Indeed I just wanted to quickly get an answer (from the classification of deflating maps which ChatGPT did flawlessly), and I am aware that I could also write a script, but I thought this is a good task for ChatGPT. I was wrong. Lesson learned. Thanks for fixing the duplicate!

I did not use a Spoiler tag since afaik they grow with the content? In any case, if someone finds a nice formatting, feel free to edit.

@MartinBrandenburg, re, sorry, you are right; I forgot this behavior of spoilers.  I thought they were like folding blocks.

@user509184, until "probably-correct" can be replaced with "correct", the person using the tool should do the checking before posting it and asking every reader to do it. But once you account for generating and correcting it's quicker to write the Python script. This is a fundamental case of the wrong tool for any job where correctness matters. That's separate from the point that the prompt given to ChatGPT likely expresses the 16 cases in a more readable format than this output.

Based on the criticism and the numbers of downvotes, I have removed the long list, the reference to ChatGPT, and instead used Peter's concise description. This makes some of the comments here obsolete, and I am sorry for that, but I think the answer is better now.

In the comments, Tobias Fritz suggested to look at the subfunctor $P' \subseteq P$ of non-empty subsets. Here the classification is much easier: Every operation $(P')^n \to P'$ is of the form $(U_1,\dotsc,U_n) \to \bigcup_{i \in T} U_i$ for a non-empty subset $T \subseteq [n]$. Hence their amount is $2^{n} - 1$.
Proof. Let $\alpha : (P')^n \to P'$ be an operation. Let $T := \alpha_{[n]}(\{1\},\dotsc,\{n\})$, this is a non-empty subset of $[n]$. Let $X$ be a set with subsets $U_1,\dotsc,U_n \subseteq X$. If $\pi : U_1 + \cdots + U_n \to X$ is the projection from the disjoint union, then $\alpha_X(U_1,\dotsc,U_n) = \alpha_{U_1 + \cdots + U_n}(U_1,\dotsc,U_n)$, and therefore we may as well assume $X = U_1 + \cdots + U_n$. The subset $A := \alpha_X(U_1,\dotsc,U_n)$ is invariant under the action of $S_{U_1} \times \cdots \times S_{U_n}$ on $U_1 + \cdots + U_n$. Hence, it has the form $\bigcup_{i \in J} U_i$ for some set $J \subseteq [n]$. If $f : X \to [n]$ is the "index projection", we have on the one hand $f(A) = J$, on the other hand $f(A) = \alpha_{[n]}(f(U_1),\dotsc,f(U_n)) = \alpha_{[n]}(\{1\},\dotsc,\{n\}) = T$, and we are done. $\checkmark$
PS: One can also show in a similar fashion (but with more effort, and extra care when $K = \mathbb{F}_2$) that for the (covariant) functor $\mathrm{Sub} : \mathbf{Vect}_K \to \mathbf{Set}$ of subspaces there $2^n$ operations $\mathrm{Sub}^n \to \mathrm{Sub}$.

PS: This proof is a non-empty subset of the proof by Peter LeFanu Lumsdaine.
